# Use loop to populate table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a table with only one column by the name of x which is a number data type. I am looking for a way to populate this table with values in successive rows by using a similar code to below.

`bcreate table sometable (x number);`

```
begin 
for i .. X loop 
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into sometable values('||i||')'; end loop; 
end;
```

How can I modify it so that I can insert whatever number of rows I set ie 100, 500 or 1000 etc?

Comment: Why dynamic SQL? There's nothing dynamic here.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without a loop:

```
insert into sometable
  with xs (x) as
  (
    select LEVEL 
    from DUAL
    connect BY LEVEL <= 100
  )
  select x from xs;
```

If you need to loop:

```
declare 
  end_loop:= 100;

begin 
for i .. end_loop loop 
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into sometable values('||i||')'; end loop; 
end;
```